# OrientDB COALESCE Function With Unexpected Results

Tags: orientdb, coalesce

Using OrientDB 2.1.2, I was trying to use the inherent COALESCE functionality and ran into some strange results.

Goal: select the maximum value of a property based on certain conditions OR 0 if there is no value for that property given the conditions.

Here's what I tried to use to produce my results.

Attempt 1: Just selecting the Maximum value of a property based on some condition - This worked as I expected... a single result
[image]

Attempt 2: Same query as before but now I'm adding an extra condition that I know will cause no results to be returned - This also worked as I expected... no results found
[image]

Attempt 3: Using COALESCE to select 0 if the result from the second query returns no results - This is where the query fails (see below). 
[image]

I would expect the result from the second query to return no results, thereby qualifying as a "NULL" result meaning that the COALESCE function should then go on to return 0.  What happens instead is that the COALESCE function is seeing the results of the inner select (which again, returns no results) as a valid non-null value, causing the COALESCE function to never return the intended "0" value.

Two questions for those who are familiar with using the OrientDB API:

1. Do you think this functionality is working properly or should an issue be filed with the orientdb issue tracker?
2. Is there another way to achieve my goal without using COALESCE or by using COALESCE in a different way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try rather:

```
select coalesce($a, 0) from ... let $a = (subquery) where ...
```

Or also this variant because the sub-select returns a result set, but the coalescence wants a single value:

```
select coalesce($a[0], 0) from ... let $a = (subquery) where ...
```

Comment: Thanks @Lvca I'll try it.  I would love to see this functionality (using a sub-select in a coalesce) handled automatically to help people who are moving from the realm of relational database SQL quickly pick up orientdb's SQL-like API.  It is much more intuitive than trying to understand that a sub-select returning no entries is treated differently than a null!  Maybe this can be a featur request for a later version of orientdb?

Comment: Absolutely, please open a new issue on our Issue Tracker (GirHub)

Comment: In general, how should subqueries be handled in a WHERE clause? like... `select foo from vertexClassA where someField = (select max(someOtherField) from vertexFieldB)` These type of queries are failing all the time because I'm expecting the result of the subquery to be treated as a primitive JSON type, not a ResultSet.  Is there a best practice for handling these type of queries?